# Vaadin 7: Filters, EntityManager per Request(hibernate), JPAContainer and push/websockets usage

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin-push

I am using Wildfly 8.1 and Vaadin 7.3.beta1.

I am starting an EntityManager in a @WebFilter and managing the transaction at that layer, that is folowing the entitymanager-per-request pattern recommended for the usage of the JPAContainer addon.

Before Vaadin 7 it was clear to me that for every event in the browser that had a listener in the server a simple HTTP Request will be made and it will go through my Filter, thus initiating a transaction before vaadin code gets executed, and properly finishing that entitymanager transaction after vaadin code executed.

But I am concernet now that Vaadin 7 supports push and might use websocket under the hood that my Filter might not allways be executed.
Will my filter run regardless of the transport being used when using @Push in the UI?

How does this work in Vaadin 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919928/39998 we should not rely in javax.servlet.Filter anymore while using @Push in Vaadin 7 UI's because it might be using websockets as the underlying transport which won't get the filter executed to start the EntityManager Transaction.

Comment: Then what is the alternative to achieve "per Request" behavior?

Comment: Sadly I have no idea yet

Comment: Im facing the same problem currently its quite sad Vaadin didnt mention an alternative solution for this problem while still propagating using the ServletFilter - see https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.hibernate.html

Comment: Same problem...  No solution. I will not use push

Comment: You can use push, but the method should not be websockets.